# ListBox with dynamic filter textbox and multiple columns results for that hits found with filter

Tags: excel, vba

That code below is a filter for listbox. Each time when i write something in my textbox in userform it will be search for all poistions that contain that letters from textbox and thos compiling result's, will be written in my listbox

Sadly it works only with 1 column. It gives me only column that i use for my search. I would like to become more columns. That list has 9 columns. How can i write it, to get rest 8 columns for each position that compile with my search in textbox?

**That code works with 1 column without problems, but if i change number of columns to 2 and add 2nd column it works for first letter and with 2nd letter i become always *Run-Time Error 381*** and the list will be filtered one more time, but without result's in column 2... only filter result's are present

Little help, that user form with code + some list to test with:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OIVg_HgMH9FpH_8H2OXuGsJzoIO4bsAp

```
Private Sub ListName_Change()

Dim i As Long
Dim arrList As Variant

'ListAvaillabe = Listbox; E1G = sheet name; ListName = textbox as filter

Me.ListAvaillabe.Clear
'I tried first only to make it with 2 columns, it doesn't work
ListAvaillabe.ColumnCount = 2
If E1G.Range("C" & E1G.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row > 1 And Trim(Me.ListName.Value) <> vbNullString Then
arrList = E1G.Range("C2:C" & E1G.Range("C" & E1G.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Value2
For i = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
    If InStr(1, arrList(i, 1), Trim(Me.ListName.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
        Me.ListAvaillabe.AddItem arrList(i, 1)
         'below should be me rest of code for other columns
        'If E1G.Cells(i, 2).Value <> vbNullString Then ListAvaillabe.List(i - 1, 2) = E1G.Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If
Next i
End If
If Me.ListAvaillabe.ListCount = 1 Then Me.ListAvaillabe.Selected(0) = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I’m sorry but I can’t really understand what you’re asking for

Comment: sorry, it was pretty late yesterday. I hope, that it explains more now

Comment: i added a file with some data and that user form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was that same problem as from my other question. It is fixed now
[Error 381 populating listbox from a sheet table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804343/error-381-populating-listbox-from-a-sheet-table/52815298#52815298)